Getting Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops when using zugferd.ps with Ghostscript
I am trying to convert a PDF file to comply with PDF/A-3 format and attach an XML file to it as well so it complies with ZUGFeRD standard. I am using a program from Ghostscript zugferd.ps but it keeps throwing this error.
Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops

I am following this official guide from Ghostscript.
This is the GS command that I am running:
gs --permit-file-read=/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/ -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFA=3 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB \
 -sZUGFeRDXMLFile=/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/invoice.xml \
 -sZUGFeRDProfile=/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/AdobeRGB1998.icc \
 -sZUGFeRDVersion=2p1 -sZUGFeRDConformanceLevel=BASIC \
 -o /Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/zugferd.pdf \ 
/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/zugferd.ps /Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/simple_pdf.pdf

Note that I am not running it with backslashes("\"), it is just here for readability.
Also it's good to note that I have AdobeRGB199.icc, and zugferd.ps in this directory.
I also tried without -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 flag and then it succeeds, but when I run it through Vera validator, it is invalid.
Let me know if you need any more info.

Did you mean -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2(with an S) or -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2(with a D)? When I put it with S it fails with the same error, when I put it with D it succeeds but when I validate it in Vera it fails and there is no attachment seen in Acrobat Reader. And about the permit tag, in the docs it has two dashes -- but I tried either way and with -dNOSAFER and it still does not work.

Hmm, yeah, with -d it passes without any issues but when I validate it it fails, and in Acrobat there is no attachment.

If I understood correctly, you suggest using GS 10.03.0?

Yup, I just installed GhostScript 10.03.1 and ran the same command and it worked. The XML is attached to the PDF when I open it in Acrobat.

Sure, great! If not, I'm using 10.03.1, enough stress for today :D

Anyway, thank you for your help and you insight!

There seems to be a problem with latest GS 10.04.0 and ZUGFeRD attachment that was not there in prior 10.03.#.
[Later edit] this is a reported problem with correctly embedded XML but may have doubled /AF entries see https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708066 and at bottom of this answer a link to, a for now updated, zugferd.ps.
An additional control for PostScript has been added and the supposed over-ride is stated as gs --permit-devices=* --permit-file-read=... ..., but that does not add the XML in the same way the prior command worked.
For Windows users a fuller working example could be.
(For 10.03.1 remove that initial --permit devices=*)!
gs[win##c].exe --permit-devices=* ^
 --permit-file-read=C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/ ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFA=3 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 ^
 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB ^
 -sZUGFeRDXMLFile=C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/invoice.xml ^
 -sZUGFeRDProfile=C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/srgb.icc ^
 -o C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/zugferd.pdf ^
 C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/zugferd.ps ^
 C:/Users/myname/Documents/einvoicing/simple_pdf.pdf

This will currently in 10.03.# produce

For 10.04.0 users download this replacement zugferd.ps file and follow the normal internal instructions at line 134 https://cgit.ghostscript.com/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi/ghostpdl.git/plain/lib/zugferd.ps?id=5d9b000c70f66f5be7bfaed1f16ef4e50d820dc6
